# How to impliment a concept of arrayList and Model class in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to impliment a concept of arrayList and Model class in javascript 
like in java we create model class and storing those model class objects in arraylist after getting all the value for suppose we getting values from xml and those values we are storing in model class and those model class objects we are storing to the arrayList object like i want to know how to do this thing in javascript 
                  thank you in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows zero effort.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList: I suppose in Javascript you'd just use an array.

Model class: if this is just properties/getters/setters in Java, you can use simple objects in Javascript. Every property becomes a field. No need to declare a class upfront. If the model class includes interesting methods, you could make a common prototype for these objects and put the methods there.

Comment: could plz give me a snippet

Comment: `var a = []; a.push( { name: 'Alice', size: 166 }); a.push( {name: 'Ben', size: 183 }); `